# Is it possible for a signal to be represented by *both* sinusoidal *and* rectangular/triangular Fourier transforms?

Tags: fourier-transform

A signal might have both continuous and discrete parts (where the "discrete" parts are regions where a sinusoidal Fourier transform would be subject to unnecessary Gibbs Noise). So I would think that it could be useful, even if it would require an entirely different implementation strategy.

If it is possible, what are some concrete examples?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask. Could you reword it to make it more clear?

Comment: Okay - I reworded it a bit. I do want to know if it's possible first though.

Comment: Your edit still isn't helping. What do you mean by a _sinusoidal_ Fourier transform or a _rectangular_ Fourier transform? Could you provide definitions or mathematical equations for whatever it is that you're getting at?

Comment: Okay, by sinusoidal Fourier transform, I mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine_transforms

By rectangular Fourier Transform, I mean square waves (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave) - each square wave can also have a frequency of "up" and "down" states.

Comment: The question is not clear for me either. Maybe try describing your motivation and the problem context. If I am right you would like to decompose a signal f(t) into the sum of sine and square waves, so f(t) = sum_i{a_i*sin_i(t)} + sum_i{b_i*sq_i(t)} + e(t), where a_i are the coeffs for the sine waves (with different frequency), b_i are the coeffs for the different square waves and e is the error term you would like to minimize by finding the right coefficients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it would be

1. Calculation costly
2. coefficient would depend on number of harmonics $N$
3. depend on error norm
4. Most probably not worth the effort -you will probably be better with wavelets instead

You can define $N$ and calculate least square error (or other error norm) as (discrete case)

$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{K-1} | f(k) - \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} A_n \cos(2p nk) + B_n \sin(2p nk) + C_n \mathrm{sq_0}(2p nk) + D_n \mathrm{sq_1}(2p nk) |^2 
$$

and find the minimum of the sum as function of $4N$ variables $A_n$, $B_n$, $C_n$, $D_n.$

The $A_n, B_n, C_n, D_n$ are your representation

Answer (score 6):

An orthogonal set of functions is required for signal decomposition.

In basic terms, orthogonality is another way of saying all the functions in the set cover the entire bandwidth of interest without overlap.

There is no such thing as a rectangular FFT that I know of, but there is in fact a rectangular set of orthogonal functions. One such example is Haar wavelets: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet.

With that said, there are applications where a signal is analyzed by more than just an orthogonal transform (such as DCT or FFT) in order to minimize Gibbs noise.

For example, in AAC compression noise is specifically detected and encoded, instead of just relying on the DCT for noisy portions of the audio (such as applause).

Depending on your application and available signal processing resources you are probably looking at a combination of approaches and signal detection to select among them.